What is the difference between the PV-move and Hash-move in move ordering in an chess engine?
I'm writing a chess engine in python and I'm trying to start implementing some move ordering techniques for more cutoffs in my negamax algorithm.
The chess programming wiki gives this suggested move order:

PV-move of the principal variation from the previous iteration of an iterative deepening framework for the leftmost path, often implicitly done by 2.
Hash move from hash tables
Winning captures/promotions
Equal captures/promotions
Killer moves (non capture), often with mate killers first
Non-captures sorted by history heuristic and that like
Losing captures (* but see below

I don't understand the difference between the Hash move from my transposition table and the PV-move? I get the PV move from the transposition table so how is it different?

Hash moves should theoretically be identical to separately maintained PV moves. In practice though, PV moves should take precedence because of the possibility of hash collisions which would slow down but not invalidate search results. You can store your PV separately from the hash table using a triangular PV table.
